# detail view override problem on saving Account record

Tags: visualforce

Visual force page

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saveAccount}" oncomplete="this.form.reset();"/>

    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"
    <apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:form>

    </apex:page>
```

Apex class

```
public PageReference saveAccount(){
    system.debug('save');
    Account acc=new Account();
    acc.Name=searchTerm;
    acc.Phone=PhonesearchTerm;
    acc.BillingCity=CitysearchTerm ;
    acc.BillingPostalCode=postalCodesearchTerm ;
    acc.Billingstate=statesearchTerm;
    acc.BillingCountry=countrysearchTerm;
    acc.BillingStreet=streetsearchTerm;
    insert acc;
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + acc.id);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
    }
now the problem is,i had overriden detail page,and my detail page is given below,
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountInactiveController" action="{!MergeActive}">
 <!--<apex:detail subject="{!Contact.id}"/> -->

</apex:page>


public with sharing class AccountInactiveController {
    public id rid {
        set;
        get;
    }
    public AccountInactiveController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    }

    public pagereference MergeActive() {
       rid = Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc = [select Id, Active_Merged_Account_Mdm__c, Merge_Active_Mdm__c from Account where id = : rid];
        system.debug('***check acc id****'+acc );
        if (acc.Merge_Active_Mdm__c == false && acc.Active_Merged_Account_Mdm__c != null ) {
                    system.debug('***check if called****' );

            pagereference page = new pagereference('/' + acc.Active_Merged_Account_Mdm__c + '?nooverride=1');
            page.setredirect(true);
            return page;
        } else {
        system.debug('***check else called****'+rid  );
            pagereference page = new pagereference('/' + rid + '?nooverride=1');
            system.debug('***8page****'+page );
            page.setredirect(true);
            return page;
        }

    }
}
```

Iam not able to see my detail view of my record.need help,thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit briefly.

Comment: i previously overriden my view page or view button.now iam trying to save record and redirecting to detail page using id.

Comment: i remove oncomplete tag on command button,it is working now